# How to extract two numbers from column of data in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, data-cleaning

I have a column in my dataset, which has the listening time of audible books. The data is stored like
***10 hours and 43 minutes***

How to extract them and change it into minutes, in a python dataframe?

I have used
`audiob_adv['time'] = audiob_adv['Listening Time'].str.extract('(\d\d)')`

But this is not working correctly.

[Image of the dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r4URh.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the regular expression that you use. You need to select one or more digits `\d+`, then you have one or more letters that are not digits you don't want to select `[^\d]+` and you want to select the digits for the minutes `\d+`. You need to change your column type to int32 to make the calculation. With the following code, you will have what you want :

```
temp_df = audiob_adv['Listening Time'].str.extract(r'(\d+)[^\d]+(\d+)').astype('int32')
audiob_adv["Time"] = temp_df.iloc[:,0]*60 + temp_df.iloc[:,1]
```

Comment: I tried to implement, it says "cannot convert float NaN to integer". I have dropped all the nulls,